# GTKmm: Attaching an EventBox to a Grid's cell in order to manage the background color

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

Searching on the Internet, I found that one way to manage the background color of a panel into a window is to create a `Gtk::EventBox` object and change its *bg color* through the method `override_background_color`.

I've a `builder` object created from a **Glade** file. It draws a simple frame (`Gtk::Window *matchWindow`) with a 8x8 *Grid* (`Gtk::Grid *Grid`).

Once the builder has been instantiated, I'd like to create a `Gtk::EventBox` through C++ code and add it to the *Grid*.
The code I wrote is the following:

FILE `Main.h`

```
[...]
private:
    Gtk::EventBox *myEventBox;
```

FILE `Main.cpp`

```
Main::Main() {
[...]    
myEventBox = new Gtk::EventBox;
BuildMatchField();
[...]
}

void Main::BuildMatchField() {
    // Set GB color of the EventBox to BLACK
    myEventBox->override_background_color(Gdk::RGBA("#000000"));

    matchWidgets.Grid->attach(*myEventBox,0,0,1,1);

    matchWidgets.Grid->show_all_children();
}
```

Running the program, no errors appears but the `BuildMatchField()` doesn't work: no black panel appears.

I followed the [Grid Example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-multi-item-containers.html.en#grid-example) into the Gnome official guide

Any suggestion?

Comment: `override_background_color()` is deprecated; use CSS instead.

Comment: Solved: actually the app worked properly; I wasn't specifying the size of the EventBox so that a 1-pixel widget has been created and it was difficult to notice it. After inserting  `myEventBox->set_size_request(width,height)` the box appeared properly.

However, can you link me some guide/example about using CSS with gtk?